# Dataframe ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, dataframe, valueerror

I have a problem when I try to add a column to a dataframe, but I get an error. What's wrong with my function?
Note: PAVARDE in lithuanian means surname. Dataframe is about President elections: https://www.vrk.lt/en/2019-prezidento/rezultatai (Election results in the second poll  (csv)).
Function:

```
def status(person):
    PAVARDE = person
    if PAVARDE == 'NAUSĖDA':
        return 'President'
    else:
        return 'looser'

president_df['winner'] = president_df[['PAVARDE']].apply(status,axis=1)
```

I got a mistake: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

What's wrong? Could you help me?

Comment: Please type out the code instead of pasting a picture. Put the code in a code block using ``` ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], [try to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) look for existing solutions first, [look for](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) simple oversights in the code, and show code and errors [as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/). As for the error: in your own words, where the code says `president_df[['PAVARDE']]`, what do you expect this to mean? Do you see how that is different from `president_df['PAVARDE']`?

Comment: Please also read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in order to understand how to post code properly, and note well that this is **not a discussion forum** - "could you help me?" is [not how we operate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).

Comment: As a general note what that error means your if statement encounters a multidimensional array: `If [1,0] == 1` this is ambiguous, should it evaluate to True, or False? Using `([1,0] == 1).all()` or any reduced this to a single True/False value. NOTE: this is simplified and works only for special arrays like numpy, pandas.Series and NOT for the normal python list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the whole column to the function but you need to pass value by value.
At first you need to remove extra square brackets, an then when you working with pd.Series you don't need `axis` argument anymore. In the end your code should look like this:

```
def status(person):
    PAVARDE = person
    if PAVARDE == 'NAUSĖDA':
        return 'President'
    else:
        return 'looser'

president_df['winner'] = president_df['PAVARDE'].apply(status)
```

or like this:

```
df['winner'] = df['PAVARDE'].apply(lambda x: 'President' if x == 'NAUSĖDA' else 'looser')
```